# Is it ok to md5 session id or memcache key?

Tags: php, session, memcached

I am getting this warning when storage object of my application is set to session.

> Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in Unknown on line 0

so I decided to Md5 session id and warning is gone now. But this code is common for all storage options like memcache and phparray. so my question is, is it ok to Md5 memcache keys or session ids? will it create some other problem ? or is there any better solution ?

Comment: md5 is known to be collision voulnerable

Comment: Remember that you can't reverse md5, so how would you know what value the session ID had subsequently? or know what memcache key to use to retrieve data from memcache?

Comment: I have getter and setter method to retrieve and store data and will pass Md5 key in both methods to do operation. and this long key I get from another server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not ok to use md5 for that because an infinite number of strings can result in the same hash. So you don't want to do that!

Is there any better solution?

Yes. Instead of trying to hack around your problem, address it! Your session id contains illegal chars or is too long! Create valid session ids!

Comment: Thanks Markus for your answer. Thing is I get some information from another server along with token which I store in my session as key and this token is the only identifier for the information I get from server so I really don't have any control to change it.

Comment: Then you have to map the foreign token with a valid token of your own and use your own token for your session.

Comment: I don't have idea how would I map the foreign token with the token I generate. Foreign token is identifier for me to retrieve and store into session or cache. now how I can map my own token to foreign token to do same operation?

Comment: Create a table with fields (id, foreignToken, token). Whenever you communicate inside your own system, use token, whenever you communicate with that foreign server, use foreignToken. Maybe you also have or provide more information about the nature of that foreign token and find out why it is an invalid token. Maybe you're doing something wrong with it in the first place.

Comment: My app is kind of library and there is no DB required for that. As you mentioned Md5 usage is not ok and I don't have control to change keys which is creating a problem for session id, I will mendate storage of tokens in memcache.

Comment: Use file storage instead of DB?!

Comment: I feel introducing file storage just to avoid one warning is not good.. no?

Comment: It looks like it's a central part of the library, but I do not know enough about your project to give further advise. Maybe you can talk to the provider of the invalid tokens and delegate the solution to them.